# Apply a function to the replacement string when matching to a regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to replace some patterns, in a String, by the call of a function upon the detected groups.

More specifically, I would like for example to transform

```
String input = "normal <upper> normal <upper again> normal";
```

into

```
String output = "normal UPPER normal UPPER AGAIN normal";
```

The regex `\<(.*?)\>"` should detect the pattern i want to transform, but using

```
output = input.replaceAll("\\<(.*?)\\>", "$1".toUpperCase());
```

doesn't work, because logically it puts `$1` to upper case, that is, nothing happens, before treating it inside the method.
Besides, the method I want to apply is to be called with the replacement string as an argument ; thus the "wrong naive way" would be something more like

```
output = input.replaceAll("\\<(.*?)\\>", transform("$1"));
```

Do you know of any trick to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idiomatic way to do it is slightly verbose:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>").matcher(input);
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(b, transform(m.group());
}
m.appendTail(b);
output = b.toString();
```

Comment: What is `buf` ? Why is there no track of the `input` String ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will correct a little thing though. Since I want to replace what is _inside_ the angle brackets (that is, what is inside the first group of the regex), I must use `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group()`.

Answer (score 1):

An example is shown [here](http://javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace_loop.shtml)

Its sad Java makes you create a separate buffer and loop building it up with m.find() only to have to re-assign it to the input string.

In perl its done in-line within the engine:   `$str =~ s/<(.*?)>/'<'.upper($1).'>'/seg;` but thats just perl, a mystery unto itself.

Comment: That seems quite exactly the same as axtavt's answer. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: No, it isn't the same.  Notice how this one uses `quoteReplacement()` on the replacement string?  Without that, you can get unexpected results or runtime exceptions if the string happens to contain backslashes or dollar signs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^<>]+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    sb.append(transform(m.group(1));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
output = sb.toString();
```

The main improvement over @axtavt's answer is the two-stage append process.

`appendReplacement()` processes the replacement string looking for dollar signs (which indicate group references) and backslashes (which are used to escape dollar signs and backslashes).  But any dollar signs in our replacement strings should be treated literally; treating them as group-reference sigils will result in garbage output or runtime exceptions.  So we disable it by passing an empty string to `appendReplacement()` and appending the actual replacement to the StringBuffer ourselves.

Note: the `quoteReplacment()` method, which I mentioned in a comment to another answer, would do the job too.  *This* approach is possible because we're looping manually, not calling `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()`, and it's both clearer (IMO) and more efficient.